# I can't create a schema database

Tags: javascript, mysql

I am working on mysql database for the first time. I tried to create a schema database.

This is what i entered:

```
CREATE SCHEMA 'Database' ;
```

and I am getting this

> error:" 16:28:00   CREATE SCHEMA 'database123' Error Code: 1064. You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near ''database123'' at line 1   0.000 sec"....

Comment: Try `CREATE SCHEMA \`Database123\`` ! Back ticks not single quotes

Answer (score 1):

Try it without quotes. If you're still getting an error, it might be that database is a reserved keyword.

Answer (score 0):

If you using mysql console:

```
mysql -u USERNAME -p;
```

> (enter password to mysql user).

```
CREATE SCHEMA `databaseName` DEFAULT CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci;
SHOW DATABASES;
```

> The list will show the created database